# Concurrent java SOAP web service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, web-services, soap

I'm developing an android application that communicates with a java SOAP web service. It works fine but I've done nothing to make the web service concurrent. I'm wondering if the web service would create a thread for every incoming request or should I have to do it.

This is the Web Method I have:

```
public class WebServer {
    public String doSomething(String arg1, int arg2) {
        //doSomething
        return string;
    }
}
```

I'm making a request from Android with the KSOAP2 library, this will be the client. I know how to create a thread inside the "doSomething" method, but I don't know how to make that thread response to the correct client.

So if the java web server running over Tomcat creates a thread for every request I have no problem, but if not, how would I achieve that?

Comment: You don't need to create threads per request. Web server already covers this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Tomcat (your app server) will manage the threads. You do not need to handle this yourself inside your Java code.